# PHP counting MYSQL rows that contain the same value in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and there is the column named 'status'. This column could contain five possible values. Now I need to sum number of rows, where the status column contains value 'canceled'. What function in the PHP I should use to count it, please? Thanks for response.

---

**EDIT:**

I think here's the complete solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
$canceledsum=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalcanceled FROM nabidka WHERE status='canceled'");
$d=mysql_fetch_assoc($canceledsum);
echo $d['totalcanceled'];
```

Comment: Actually, I'm a newer and I'm learning, so this is probably the reason. Thank you.

Comment: Counting, sorting and other MySQL operations are always faster than PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE status='canceled'
```

or this query that will count all rows for all different status values:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY status
```

**Edit:** if you want to count only records created on the current month:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE create_date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
GROUP BY status
```

here `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')` will return the first day of the current month, if you don't have records created in the future it will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for solving my goal (and more).

Comment: As already mentioned, I have the column named status.

`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM quote WHERE status='canceled'` 

Thanks to your code is to counting included each row that meet the condition status='canceled'.

But I need to include to counting the second condition.

I have a column create_date and need to be included to counting only rows in this column according to the current month.

This is a column of type DATE, so today's date appears in the column as follows: 03/23/2014

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm bothering you, but this is something what could learn me a lot...

Comment: And what about this?
`WHERE status='canceled' AND MONTH(create_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())`

But this returns me 0 as well as your code. In the DB there's 1 record according both conditions.

Comment: @user3424754 using just MONTH() function will be fine as long as you don't have records from different years, but it won't make use of an index on the create_date column. Is `create_date` a DATE column? or a varchar?

Comment: create_date is DATE type

Comment: Could be this fixed by this addition?

`AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(create_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())`

But both codes (this and yours) returns me 0, so I have to find a fault elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `PHP` to count, you might directly use sql.

Fire this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE status = 'canceled';
```

As for how to fire queries and getting data from PHP, please refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the response Tzar.